# What would be a good regexp for identifying the "original message" prefix in gmail?

Tags: python, regex, roundup

An example signature may be:

```
On Tue, Mar 20, 2012 at 2:38 PM, Johnny Walker <johnny.talker@gmail.com> wrote:
```

And then follows the quoted reply. I do have a discrete sensation this is locale specific though which makes me a sad programmer.

The reason I ask for this is because [roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net) doesn't strip these correctly when replying through gmail to an issue. And I think `origmsg_re` is the config.ini variable I need to set alongside `keep_quoted_text = no` to fix this.

Right now it's the default `origmsg_re = ^[>|\s]*-----\s?Original Message\s?-----$`

**Edit:** Now I'm using `origmsg_re = 
^On[^<]+<.+@.+>[ \n]wrote:[\n]` which works with some gmail clients that break lines that are too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will match gmails prefix in a pretty safe manner. It ensures that there are 3 commas and the liter text On ... wrote

```
On([^,]+,){3}.*?wrote:
```

If the regex should match in a case insensitve way then don't forget to add the modifier.

```
if re.search("On([^,]+,){3}.*?wrote:", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Kind Regards, Buckley

```
Match the characters “On” literally «On»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^,]+,){3}»
   Exactly 3 times «{3}»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «{3}»
   Match any character that is NOT a “,” «[^,]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “,” literally «,»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “wrote:” literally «wrote:»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Thanks, I eventually used this though: `origmsg_re = ^On.+<.+@.+> wrote:$`